# Приведение БД к 3й нормальной форме

Tags: база-данных

День добрый. Помогите, пожалуйста, осилить сей вопрос. Создал БД, в ней 17 полей + id, после недолгих раздумий решил привести к 3 НФ, но не могу определить какие объединить, а какие разбить по таблицам и какие сделать ключами.

Подробнее о переменных:

- id - собственно просто инкремент,
- idWP - номер рабочего места, не НУЛЛ, уникальный,
- netname - сетевое имя, не НУЛЛ,
- shop - цех, не НУЛЛ
- otdel - отдел цеха, не НУЛЛ,
- server - серверная
- serverbox - шкаф,
- panel - патч-панель,
- gnezdpatch - номер гнезда в панеле,
- comm - коммутатор,
- portcomm - номер порта в коммутаторе,
- vlan - вирт. LAN,
- ip - ip адрес (в принципе это розетка, принадлежит кабинету), уникальный,
- room - кабинет в отделе,
- tel - телефон в кабинете,
- username - имя пользователя, не НУЛЛ,
- date - дата установки, не НУЛЛ,
- advance - примечание.

Из всего этого я делал следующие заключения:

1. Допустим человек уволился, соответственно удаляется из БД номер рабочего места, сетевое имя, имя пользователя, дата, примечание. Но я не теряю ни ip адреса, ни номера кабинета, ни цеха и т.д.
2. Если удаляется кабинет (разрушили или ещё что) то теряются все юзеры, ИП, телефоны в кабинете и т.п. Ну и тоже самое по иерархии с патч панелями, коммутаторами, шкафами и серверной.

Рад услышать любые обоснованные советы, критику и т.п. Заранее спасибо.

[image: Диаграмма БД].

**Добавлено.**

Пересмотрел и сделал другой вариант, посмотрите может здесь всё верно?

[image: Диаграмма БД]

В таблице ROOMofDEP будут описываться все кабинеты отдела и находящиеся в них телефоны рабочие места, ip адрес я отсюда убрал, чтобы можно было пустить ветку до серверной, в итоге меня теперь смущает тот факт, что у меня круг получился, т.к. от ИП до серверной я попал, но в тоже время серверная находится в каком-то цехе, правильно ли я сделал? Думаю на диаграмме все отношения видны.

Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Есть смысл уточнить базу данных.

Comment: Что именно уточнить нужно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- картинки маленькие, ничего не видно, поэтому прокомментирую только то что вижу сразу)
- общий принцип моделирования- просто рисуете сущности, называя их своими именами и связи между ними.
- названия в бд принято писать через подчёркивания а не camel-case-ом. потому что большей части субд наплевать на регистр букв :) Это я к тому что ROOMofDEP надо переименовать в room_of_dep илл в room2dep; Тоже самое со всеми остальными таблицам.
- зачем shop_name в отдельную табличку?
- depOfshop странное название. Это ведь просто department?. То что он входит в магазин в названии таблички отражать не надо. Тоже самое со всеми остальными таблицам.
- Что значит таблица main? Такой быть не может :) может быть user?
- Не удаляйте пользователя, если его уволили. Потом всё равно захочется посмотреть всех кто сидел за конкретным рабочим местом в конкретную дату. Если чувак уволился ставьте флаг "удалён" + всем связи вида рабочее место->ip адресс нужно сделать через таблички связи с датами вида id1, id2, from_date, to_date.
- по совокупности всех замечаний - первая диаграмма лучше :) там хоть понятно какие есть сущности и как они связаны.

Comment: shop - это у меня так называемый Цех на заводе, в который входят dep (отделы). В первой диаграмме в некоторых таблицах, больше 1й зависимости, будут теряться нужные данные, по уволенным хорошая идея, спасибо. Пойду реализовывать.

Comment: Shop это цех??? Никогда бы не подумал. Shop это магазин :) Цех лучше назвать workshop. Про отдельную табличку не убедили. Заведите у цехов поле "имя" и вписывайте туда "15-ый с половиной 5 цех". Про первую диаграмму вы меня не поняли. Она тоже отстой, но чуть-чуть получше. Там хотя-бы названия более понятные, за исключением конечно же place2. :) Сделаете для начала вариант с человеческими названиями и выгладывайте на второй круг критики.

Comment: Хорошо, можно ещё такой вопрос, когда я связываю таблицы через первичный и внешний ключи, кто является старшим? первичный? просто столкнулся с неудобством при заполнении таблиц, я хотел сверху вниз заполнить т.е. сначала цех, потом отдел, потом кабинеты, а потом добавлять пользователей и уже из существующих данных выставлять где кто работает, а на деле у меня наоборот, приходится от кабинета вверх идти, в противном случае он не сохраняет данные и ругается :(

Comment: Ну если ругается - отругай его в ответ :)) "ругается" это не баг репорт и не сообщение об ошибке. Да и вообще не надо бежать впереди паровоза, сначала надо схему составить более-менее приличнную, а уже потом данные туда вбивать. Я же не телепат, я не вижу куда и что вы вбиваете. Вдруг вы внешние ключи "наоборот" повернули)

Answer (score 0):

По второй диаграмме зачем в DEP первичный ключ - id цеха? или они с iddep должны идти в связке, или, что логичнее, iddep единолично должен быть первичным ключом. Та же история с ROOM. заведите на каждую таблицу суррогатные ключи - будет проще как то